# keep data obtained in onResponse method available throughout the class

Tags: java, android, json, response, okhttp

Basically in my android app I want user to search cities around the world, thus I am using an api to get all the cities of the world and storing in an `ArrayList`, this has been done in the `onResponse` method of okhttp library and after that the list becomes empty. This array list holds values only in `onResponse` but I want to use it in my entire class after the execution. Can anyone give me any ideas on that? Here is the code.

```
onCreate(){
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json")
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                fullObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                JSONArray s = fullObject.names();
                for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray citiesOfOneCoutry = null;
                    citiesOfOneCoutry = fullObject.getJSONArray(s.getString(i));
                    for(int j=0; j<citiesOfOneCoutry.length();j++) {
                        allCities.add(citiesOfOneCoutry.getString(j));
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: in for "+allCities.size());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: outside for "+allCities.size()); //gives full size.
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: outside try "+allCities.size()); //gives full size
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "outside response inside oncreate"+allCities.size()); //gives 0
```

}

I see in the logs that message from outside `onResponse` one is first and then the callback is getting executed. that is quite understandable but I want trick to get this `ArrayList` after response execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the nature of asynchronous operations, they don't complete in the order you wrote them.  `allCities` data will not be available in your `onCreate` method because it hasn't had a chance to execute yet.  The trick to using it outside of `onResponse` is to move the code that relies on the response to its own method.

```
private void updateUI() {
     // Your code that relies on 'allCities'
}
```

and then in `onResponse`, call `updateUI` (or whatever you call it) after you populate `allCities` --

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    try {
        fullObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
        JSONArray s = fullObject.names();
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray citiesOfOneCoutry = null;
            citiesOfOneCoutry = fullObject.getJSONArray(s.getString(i));
            for(int j=0; j<citiesOfOneCoutry.length();j++) {
                allCities.add(citiesOfOneCoutry.getString(j));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: in for "+allCities.size());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: outside for "+allCities.size()); //gives full size.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: outside try "+allCities.size()); //gives full size
    updateUI();
}
```